# How to run pip for python3.9 in VS code server?

Tags: python, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote

I have hosted a vs code server to run my python files but when I am doing `pip` it is showing `bash: pip: command not found` I wanted to know how can I install modules in the same server
Thanks for your help

Comment: If you are running python 3, try `pip3` instead.

Comment: its not working

Comment: If you are sure it is installed, you can try calling it with your python interpreter with `python -m pip`

Comment: thats the problem i cant use pip not even `python -m pip`

Comment: You have to install python and/or pip on the remote machine as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while running code-server through coder. Was thrown off by the new environment, but the solution is actually fairly simple.

- Start by opening up a terminal (F1 > Terminal: Create New Terminal).
- Type `lsb_release -a`. If your environment is like mine, you'll see it's a standard Debian. The pitfall here is that its apt sources haven't been updated.
- Type `apt update` to update the sources and get the packages.
- Type `apt install python3-pip`

Hope this helps!